# PostgreSQL uses only one core

Tags: postgresql

I am doing a simple groupby query and htop tells me only 1 out of 4 is used (100% cpu for that 1). Why does not PostgreSQL server use all cores? how can I make it use them?

PostgreSQL 13.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit
[image]

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(to_address)            wallet_address,
               row_number() over () as wallet_id
from wallet
group by 1
```

Settings:

```
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 8
```

Here is the plan:

```
Unique  (cost=1603531.10..1603711.83 rows=24097 width=51) (actual time=16835.332..17429.003 rows=1426640 loops=1)
"  Buffers: shared hit=300 read=1438917, temp read=231858 written=321368"
  ->  Sort  (cost=1603531.10..1603591.35 rows=24097 width=51) (actual time=16835.329..17230.725 rows=1426640 loops=1)
"        Sort Key: to_address, (row_number() OVER (?))"
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 92168kB
"        Buffers: shared hit=300 read=1438917, temp read=231858 written=321368"
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1595732.53..1601777.26 rows=24097 width=51) (actual time=13468.075..15928.567 rows=1426640 loops=1)
"              Buffers: shared hit=297 read=1438917, temp read=208094 written=297545"
              ->  Group  (cost=1595732.53..1601476.04 rows=24097 width=43) (actual time=13468.065..15578.762 rows=1426640 loops=1)
                    Group Key: to_address
"                    Buffers: shared hit=297 read=1438917, temp read=208094 written=297545"
                    ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1595732.53..1601355.56 rows=48194 width=43) (actual time=13468.063..15276.507 rows=2425913 loops=1)
                          Workers Planned: 2
                          Workers Launched: 2
"                          Buffers: shared hit=297 read=1438917, temp read=208094 written=297545"
                          ->  Sort  (cost=1594732.51..1594792.75 rows=24097 width=43) (actual time=13263.770..14203.513 rows=808638 loops=3)
                                Sort Key: to_address
                                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 37928kB
"                                Buffers: shared hit=297 read=1438917, temp read=208094 written=297545"
                                Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 38040kB
                                Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 49936kB
                                ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=1592737.69..1592978.66 rows=24097 width=43) (actual time=7763.104..10554.263 rows=808638 loops=3)
                                      Group Key: to_address
                                      Batches: 45  Memory Usage: 4249kB  Disk Usage: 267200kB
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=281 read=1438917, temp read=187056 written=276447"
                                      Worker 0:  Batches: 45  Memory Usage: 4249kB  Disk Usage: 264072kB
                                      Worker 1:  Batches: 53  Memory Usage: 4249kB  Disk Usage: 441288kB
                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on wallet  (cost=0.00..1562029.75 rows=12283175 width=43) (actual time=0.034..2618.692 rows=9826128 loops=3)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=281 read=1438917
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=87
Planning Time: 0.387 ms
Execution Time: 17515.667 ms
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (no screen shots please!) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. And also show us the value of the configuration parameters `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` and `max_parallel_workers`

Comment: We would have to see the query itself to give meaningful advice.  Some operations don't parallelize well.

Comment: The query uses two cores. But you the bottleneck is the sorting/grouping done on disk, because `work_mem` is too small

Comment: Note that `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 4):

When you make a single connection to PostgreSQL, it spins up a new process to handle your connection.  With that process, it is assigned to one core to perform all the work that it needs done.  That is the default behavior.  The other cores will then be available for use by other connections and their respective queries.  If you want more cores to be used, one way would be to make more connections and run more queries at the same time but I don't think that is what you intend.

In some cases, some types of queries will use more than one core.  See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/parallel-query.html for a brief description.  Please see the section on settings on the above page that are necessary as also referenced by a comment by a_horse_with_no_name.

Without your query plan available, it will be difficult to tell if your query is parallelizable from your problem description.