# Using Posgresql on different cores

Tags: postgresql

reading from the web, if not mistaken, I understand that Postgres runs only on one core.  My question: if I have 2 Postgres programs on the same workstation, one runs on PGAdmin and the other one runs on DBeaver, would Postgres use 1 core for PGAdmin and 1 core for DBeaver?
Also, is there function that I can use to check how many core Postgres is using?

Thank you in advance for educating me on this!

Comment: This Question belongs on the sister site: [DBA.StackExchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "*reading from the web*" - can you share you sources, please?

Comment: Hello, I actually read it on a post on Stack Overflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71416125/postgresql-uses-only-one-core#:~:text=When%20you%20make%20a%20single,connections%20and%20their%20respective%20queries.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out to a different section of to ask this question. I am a newbie. Let me post my question there/